# Decimal conversion - NumberFormatException

Tags: java, double, biginteger

I have

`String number = 1.0E7;`

I want its numeric equivalent i.e display it as a

```
double x = 10000000.0000
```

How can I go about it?

I have tried `Double number = Double.valueOf(number);`

but getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Comment: `Double.valueOf("1.0E7");` works as expected. Show all your code.

Comment: Is that `;` part of the value of `number`?

Comment: You can use numberFormat.

Comment: Don't use the same variable name for the String and the Double!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format a number with 4 decimals, use `String.format("%.4f", num)` as in the following example:

```
public class k {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    String number = "1.0E7";
    Double num = Double.valueOf(number);
    System.out.println("Double="+ num + " Formatted Double=" + String.format("%.4f", num));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
String=1.0E7 Formatted Double=10000000,0000
```

As you can see, my locale uses `,` as decimal separator.

Comment: You could simplify the last line to `System.out.format("Double=%s Formatted Double=%1$.4f%n", num);`

Answer (score 1):

You want to **format** a double value.

```
String it = String.format("%f", 1.0e7);
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This will work perfectly.

```
double number=1.0E7;
System.out.println(number);
NumberFormat formatter=new DecimalFormat();
System.out.println(formatter.format(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs of [`Double#toString(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29), you can see that

> If m is less than 10-3 or greater than or equal to 107, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation.

That is why even if you parse the value to a double, you'll get the scientific notation only, which is `1.0E7`.

You can do something like this to print the double value as you want.

```
String number = "1.0E7";
String desiredFormat = String.format("%f", Double.parseDouble(number));
System.out.println(desiredFormat); // Prints 10000000.000000
```

Or may be use a [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) if you want.

```
String number = "1.0E7";
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(number)));
```